# Unable to exclude directory from rewriting rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to do this in many ways, but I really cannot exclude directory "progress" from wordpress rewriting rules in .htaccess. I found many solutions but none of them seems to be working.
.htaccess in root directory of wp contains:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried to use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(progress/.*)$
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^progress($|/) - [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(admin|progress)/
```

and I even tried to put Alias /progress /home/website/progress to httpd.conf but it still not working properly. Surely, mod_rewrite is installed and working, it redirects me to index.php that shows 404 error when I trying to access the directory...

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_exclude_a_folder_from_Wordpress_permalinks.html).

```
#Change 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#to:
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of your attempts should work when used correctly. As the rules are tested sequentially, you need to put the exceptional case in front of your existing Wordpress rule:

```
RewriteRule ^progress($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Or when using the additional condition (well ok, here the order of the conditions does not matter as they *all* have to be fulfilled):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|progress)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the directory `progress` actually exist? What's inside it?

Where are you placing the code you have provided within the context of the `.htaccess`?

The line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` will mean the rewrite rule is ignored if the request translates to a real directory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following on .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Use the folder name that you want to exclude from wordpress htaccess rule as RewriteBase, so basically try writing following in .htaccess file for the folder "FOLDER_NAME"

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /FOLDER_NAME
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And place this .htaccess file into the folder with name "FOLDER_NAME". Please let me know if that works.